# JAWS not reading dropdown list items created using unordered list when using SelectBoxIt js

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jaws-screen-reader

I have below dropdown list code which is generated using selectboxit js lib. JAWS is not reading the items in select list when focus in on the items. I have tried adding aria-label and title attributes on li, a , span and even i element but its still not reading. What attribute do i need to add so that JAWS can read it properly on focus. Focus is going properly on li element when up and down arrow is used.

```
<ul id="ddlSubReason_1SelectBoxItOptions" class="selectboxit-options selectboxit-list" tabindex="-1" role="listbox" aria-hidden="true">
   <li id="0" data-val="" data-disabled="false" class="selectboxit-option selectboxit-option-first selectboxit-selected" role="option" aria-label="">
   <a class="selectboxit-option-anchor">
   <span class="selectboxit-option-icon-container">
   <i class="selectboxit-option-icon  selectboxit-container"></i></span></a></li>
   <li id="1" data-val="29" data-disabled="false" class="selectboxit-option" role="option" aria-label="Selection text placeholder 1">
   <a class="selectboxit-option-anchor">
   <span class="selectboxit-option-icon-container">
   <i class="selectboxit-option-icon  selectboxit-container"></i></span>
   Selection text placeholder 1</a></li>
   <li id="2" data-val="28" data-disabled="false" class="selectboxit-option" role="option" aria-label="Selection text placeholder 2">
   <a class="selectboxit-option-anchor">
   <span class="selectboxit-option-icon-container">
   <i class="selectboxit-option-icon  selectboxit-container"></i></span>
   Selection text placeholder 2</a></li>
   <li id="3" data-val="55" data-disabled="false" class="selectboxit-option" role="option" aria-label="Selection text placeholder 3">
   <a class="selectboxit-option-anchor">
   <span class="selectboxit-option-icon-container">
   <i class="selectboxit-option-icon  selectboxit-container"></i></span>
   Selection text placeholder 3</a></li>  
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posting the solution that worked for me which i found on this link - https://webaim.org/discussion/mail_thread?thread=6559

1. Moved tabindex="0" into the surrounding span, since this should handle keyboard interaction.
2. Added IDs and tabindex="-1" to all elements with role=option.
3. Added aria-activedescendant to the container with role=combobox, which should be dynamically updated to point to the selected. (I was missing this particular point which fixed the issue for me)

Answer (score 0):

You have `aria-hidden="true"` on the parent container (`<ul>`).  That will hide all children from the screen reader and nothing will be announced.  Try removing it.

.<ul id="ddlSubReason_1SelectBoxItOptions" class="selectboxit-options selectboxit-list" tabindex="-1" role="listbox" <s>**aria-hidden="true"**</s>>

Comment: Its still not working after removing aria-hidden. When I focus on Dropdown it reads all the options at once but when I focus on each option its not reading individual options on focus.

Comment: The code snippet in the OP works fine with a screen reader **after removing `aria-hidden`**. I had to add a dummy `href` to the `<a>` elements to make them keyboard focusable, but I was able to TAB to them and all of them were read.  Without removing `aria-hidden`, they were **not** read.